# Is there optimal way to find substring with reapiting pattern in a string in C++?

Tags: c++, substring

I am struggling with a problem that I need to solve for my online classes. Normally my teacher would gladly help but now there is no possibility to contact him. The problem is following:

If there are two identical substrings  next to eachother we can compress that by writing it as (substring). So, we can write zz as (z) and zzzz as ((z)) or zzzzzzzzzzbb as (((z)))(z)(b). Given a compressed text check if compression was done correctly, if possible - decompress it and check if compression was done in an optimal way, possibly by optimal compressing it again.

I have already written a function to check whether compression was done correctly, decompressing function and optimal compressing but only for string with only one pattern (like gorgorgorgorgorgor or zzzzzz) and when the pattern is known.

```
std::string ifreapeats(std::string tes, std::string dotes){

int iloraz = dotes.length() / tes.length();
int pot2 = highestpow2(iloraz);
int roznica = iloraz - pot2;

std::string finale;

finale = "";

int logar = int(log(iloraz) / log(2));

    for(int i = 0; i < logar; ++i)
    {
        finale += '(';
    }

    finale += tes;

    for (int i = 0; i < logar; ++i)
    {
        finale += ')';
    }

    if (roznica == 1)
        return finale + tes;

    if (roznica == 0)
        return finale;

    std::string dotes2 = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < roznica; ++i)
    {
        dotes2 += tes;
    }

    finale += ifreapeats(tes, dotes2);

    return finale;}
```

Where highestpow2 returns higest power of 2 smaller or equal than given number. Now I don't know how to apply this to more complicated strings, where there is more than one pattern and there are sequences without a pattern. For example aabbbaabbbxyzyz. It should return back ((a)(b)b)x(yz). I guess finding longest patterned substring might work but I have no idea how to apply this. Also this is problem way harder than what we have done earlier on our IT class. If it is not problem I would like some explanation so I can help other students in my class (everyone is hoping I will manage to finish the problem and give them a hand too).

Sorry for some grammatical mistakes I possibly made. I also might have left some variables names in polish, for what I apologize too.

Comment: How is `(z)` a compression of `zz`?  The former takes three characters, the latter takes 2 characters, thus `zz` is more compressed than `(z)`.  Also, why isn't `zzzzzzzzzz` equal to `((((z))))`?

Comment: what is an "optimal" compression? I suppose the one that results in the shortest compressed string, but if the assignment asks for "optimal compression" I'd expect that it comes with a definition of what that should be

Comment: Finding a repeating substring forms the core of Huffman coding, and there is plenty of literature that explains the basic approach, and the basic algorithms for doing so. You either don't know the algorithm, the basic approach, or you know it but have a question about implementing it in C++. If you do not know the basic algorithm, there's plenty of literature (incl Wikipedia) available, out there, that you can read. Copy/pasting it verbatim, here, accomplishes nothing useful. If you have a specific C++ application question, about this, you need to clarify what is your ***specific*** question.

Comment: Our teacher wrote that for this specific problem the most compressed version is the one, where all paterns are compressed. I think () signs maybe doesn't weight anything for this case. zzzzzzzzzz can be written by (zzzzz) but it is not optimal so we rewrite it as (zzzz)zz which equals ((zz))(z) which equals (((z)))(z). I hope now I clarified this

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Apparently `((((z))))` means 2^4 `z`s (because there are 4 pairs of parentheses).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am in high school and this problem is waaay beyond what we have done earlier. I have been searching it in many different ways but I didn't came across anything that would satisfy this problem. I only found some articles referring to finding if substring repeats anywhere in given string but it wasn't anything I thought might be helpfull. If it is I would be very grateful if you gave me some link or explained how to apply Huffman coding to this exact problem. Thank you very much and sorry for not clarifying the problem!

Comment: @Stanislaw if you're not sure whether parentheses count for output length, then you need to ask your instructor. Send them an e-mail. There's no way we'll know what they want in that regard.

Comment: @JohnFilleau As I said - besides sending homework there is no contact with him. If there was I would not be asking here :/  But that is the one thing he wrote in the assignment. Parentheses doesn't count so we are trying to get the smallest number of letters in the output. That's for sure

Comment: @Stanis your teacher didn't escape into the woods and burn off their fingerprints. I guarantee they have a work e-mail. Possibly listed on your school website. I think it's fine for you to seek help here, but I also think you should have contact with your teacher. If they don't have an e-mail listed, you see if their boss has one. If their boss doesn't, you try the principal. Or a general "contact@school.gov.pl" email address.

Comment: What kind of teachers they have these days, that are completely unreachable like that? What a sad state of affairs. When I was in high school, as you are now, I talked and discussed things with my instructors, face to face, in class, ***every day***. It's a good thing that I did. After all, there was no stackoverflow.com back then. So, all I had to help me figure everything out was my wits. And my teachers.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I tried contacting him, and as well did others, but there is no responce since many days so I have to reach to other sources of help. Also he was really good teacher, but I sense that now, when there is this whole self-learning and remote teaching, he can't use hs charisma and he can't help us much because he does not see us face-to-face. I don't know why he doesn't use Zoom or sth like that for unknown reasons. I think he might have gotten sick or sth but it's just my guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't proven that this approach produces an optimal "compression", but my intuition is to start with the longest repetition and go inwards. If this isn't optimal, then the task is way above high school level task in my opinion.

The idea is following: Search for longest repetition. Once you have found it, then the string can be divided into parts ABBC where B is the repetition and A and C are the substrings before and after repetition. Result is given by concatenating compression of A, '(', compression of B, ')' and compression of C. If no repetition is found, then compression is the input string.

You can use the following algorithm, written in pseudo code:

```
// size(S) is the size of the string
// substr(S, Pos, L) is substring of S with length L starting from Pos
// substr(S, Pos) is substring of S starting from Pos until the end of S
// S is the input string
compress(S)
    if size(S) < 2
        return S     // strings shorter than 2 cannot have repetition
    L = size(S) / 2  // L is initially longest possible repetition
    while L > 0
        for I = 0 ... size(S) - 2*L
            Left  = substr(S, I    , L)
            Right = substr(S, I + L, L)
            if Left == Right    // repetition found
                Beforeleft = substr(S, 0      , I)
                AfterRight = substr(S, I + 2*L)
                return
                    compress(Beforeleft) +
                    '(' +
                    compress(Left) +
                    ')' +
                    compress(AfterRight)
        L--     // no repetition of this length found; search for shorter
    return S    // no repetition of any length was found
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to apply this to cpp and give feedback whether I managed to do so!

Comment: It works, it is fast and accurate! Thank you very much!!! And (what is most important) I perfectly understand it and I can explain this to my classmates! Moreover - it is much simpler and shorter than code I wrote which in total had over 150 lines.